# Laravel 9 authentication without package showing error

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-authentication, laravel-9, laravel-api

I've created a login route and it is working ok , but when trying to store data of authenticated users it is showing an error that GET method is not supported but I'm using POST method. But it is getting the below URL as GET method.

> "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login"
>
> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
> POST.

**My Login route**

```
Route::post('/login',[UserController::class,'login'])->name('login');
```

**Response after login**

```
 {
 "person": {
 "_token": "WBHtlTsFtJOSdWx28nHMbtbQyUBB1vkSTjkhpb8t",
 "first_name": "Navid",
 "last_name": "Anjum",
 "email": "nav@gmail.com",
 "password": "11111111"
        }
}
```

**Route to insert data**

```
   Route::post('page/create',[PageController::class,'store'])
->middleware('auth:api')->name('page.create');
```

Comment: make sure you send auth token and csrf token with your post request

Comment: also make sure you send application/json header so that Laravel knows its an api response required and not a redirect to the login route (which you don't have)

Comment: Is `Route::post('/login'` an `api` route?

Comment: Try php artisan route:cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used Laravel sanctum to fix it.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function () {
Route::post('page/create',[PageController::class,'store'])->name('page.create');
Route::post('page/post',[PostController::class,'store'])->name('post.create');
Route::post('/page/{pageId}/attach-post',[PostController::class,'from_page'])->name('page.post');});
```

In httm->kernel sanctum was commented out.So that's why It did not work previously when I tried with it.

```
 'api' => [
        \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:cache
php artisan view:clear

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).